How to troubleshoot an H-bridge motor driver circuit?
I am running into a problem with my custom motordriver. It was designed to control two small 3-phase  sensorless brushless motors powered by a 3S battery. It is based on an STM evaluation board (STSPIN3202.) The heart of the evaluation board is an STSPIN32F0A. The STSPIN32F0A is a microcontroller (STM32) and gate driver/control logic in one package.
On the evaluation board, I got the motor to spin but only in open loop control. When switching to closed loop it stalls. The control method I used is 6-step, in which the open loop is just a sequence.
For my custom motor driver, I copied the schematic of the evaluation board from its datasheet.

Figure 1 Evaluation board STSPIN3202 datasheet

Figure 2 Custom motor driver schematic
Since I use sensorless feedback, I didn’t copy the optional Hall effect sensor part. I changed the type of MOSFETs used. Instead of the STD140N6F7 I used the PSMN011-30YLC.
I ordered too little components so I came to the idea to use STD140N6F7 MOSFETs instead but I had to flip them on the PCB to match the footprint. Now I have an exact copy of the schematic.
I wrote some simple code to start the motor which works on the evaluation board, but on both motor drivers on my PCB it doesn’t.
At first not even a PWM signal was going to the MOSFETs.  When I turned off the current limit (reassign the pin to GPIO output) I got a signal.

Figure 3 shows the PWM signal on LSV but is the same on LSU and LSW. This looks the same as on the evaluation board but instead it is shifted into the negative area.

Figure 4 shows the signal on HSW but this is the same as HSU and HSV. This signal doesn’t look anywhere near like what it does on the evaluation board.

Figure 5 shows what kind of signal the motors get. No wonder they don’t turn. For the other motor driver, the signals shown in figure 1,2 and 3 are the same.
What could be the problem? The SENSEN and SENSEP are I think just for the current limiter and the sensorless control which doesn’t work right now on the evaluation board. I also copied the sensorless control part of the STSPIN3202, but I think that should not matter since we are just trying to use open loop control.
I also checked the connectivity of all the parts but everything looks to be connected correctly. What do I do now?
Datasheets:

https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/steval-spin3202.html
https://www.st.com/en/motor-drivers/stspin32f0a.html
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/std140n6f7.pdf
https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/PSMN011_30YLC-1358245.pdf


Well, subdivide the problem; do you see the MCU pins driving active signals? (Or if integrated, can you remap them to GPIOs to inspect?) Where between MCU and MOSFETs is the signal lost? Are the sense signals in the right order?  Can you "fake" a sense signal and detect it on the MCU (remapping as necessary)? (Do you understand the "sensorless" state machine/control?) Similarly on the software side, where between peripherals and user code are the signals going? Are peripherals, HAL (if applicable), etc. configured correctly? What else differs between the two platforms?

I have tried to divide te problem. Before I completly assembled the second motordriver part of my PCB I ran the simple program. Which resulted in the signal which could be seen on the evaluationboard. So my guess is that it is the mosfet circuitry. The whole sesnorless part doesnt really matter for open loop control. This is not a software issue but more of a hardwore I suspect.

Also, the images aren't doing much here: the schematics aren't legible, so we don't know what LSV, HSV, etc. actually are; the scope waveforms are also illegible. Zoom in on the waveforms to show a few cycles clearly defined, and please double-check that your images/screenshots/photos clearly show the thing they are representing (e.g. I can barely make out a wiggly line on the screen in the last image, but certainly not its measure).

LSV stands for Low Side and the V is the phase, HSV stands for High Side. I can change the images but that wont change that its just a noisy signal with a pattern in it. I will change the images for the schematic.

Ok, that defines the MOSFETs and connected nets. What about the gate drivers? MCU? What about the waveforms along the same path?
